# Sinai billiard isomorphic to hard spheres problem

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, billiards

I have heard that Sinai's famous results on the ergodicity of $n$ hard spheres defined on a $d$ dimensional hypercube with periodic boundaries is isomorphic to a billiard (from which it was proved), now known as the Sinai billiard. That is, a billiard again defined on a $d$ dimensional flat torus except with a solid disk/cylinder of radius $r$ removed from its centre. The informal explanation for this is that the collision of hard spheres occurs when the centres of the spheres are within a distance $2r$ from each other. So, somehow the collisions of point/billiard particles with this circular scatterer is equivalent to a collision of two hard spheres?

What is the mathematical explanation of this isomorphism? In particular, how does one reconcile the fact that with $n$ hard spheres, there are more than just 'one' collision happening at once? i.e. $3$ sphere collisions or indeed multiple $2$ sphere collisions not happening about some central point (as the billiard construction seems to suggest). I suspect part of the isomorphism involves 'stripping away' some of these complicated 'physical' effects, but it is hard to imagine how. Is it also true that ergodic problem involving just two hard spheres is equivalent to that involving $n$ of them?

Comment: If nobody has an answer after a few days, you could ask Nandor Simanyi.  He is probably the top expert on this material still active.

Comment: @JohnSamples Yes, all the relevant information seems to be here: https://web.ma.utexas.edu/mp_arc/c/05/05-348.pdf. However I can't see how (or indeed if) the hard spheres problem is reduced to billiards. Two citations deep, I found the book Ergodic Theory by Cornfeld, ..., Sinai. It was referenced in "Hard ball systems are completely hyperbolic (Szasz)" in the statement - "The claimed isomorphy for one-dimensional particles, however, is well-known, and for its simple proof we can refer, for instance, to Section 4 of Chapter 5 in [C-F-S(1981)].". However that referenced chapter is about IET's..

Comment: According to Wikipedia, this problem (on the ergodicity of a system of $n$ hard spheres) is still open -- Sinai announced a proof in 1963, but never published the full proof, and in 1987 declared that the announcement was premature.  Presumably one can identify the movement of $n$ hard spheres in $d$ dimensions with movement within a (complicated) billiard in $n\cdot d$ dimensions, if that helps.

Comment: @mjqxxxx Not aware of that. Could you link the wiki page, please?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yakov_Sinai